# Cannot load multiple values in Dojo Name Text Box

Tags: dojo, xpages

Using a name picker to choose multiple values from my NAB, and want to load the values the user selects in a Dojo Name Text Box. I can load multiple values into the Dojo List Text Box, but they load with the hierarchal name, e.g. Bryan Smith/Acme. I only get the first value when I use the Dojo Name Text Box.

My code is below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">

    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1"
            formName="operatingMarketsForm">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>

    <xe:namePicker id="namePicker6" dialogTitle="Please Choose"
        pickerIcon="/iconSearch16.png" for="djextNameTextBox1">
        <xe:this.dataProvider>
            <xe:dominoNABNamePicker addressBookSel="db-name"
                groups="false" nameList="people">
                <xe:this.addressBookDb><![CDATA[#{javascript:var server:String = @Name("[CN]",session.getCurrentDatabase().getServer());
return server + "!!" + "names.nsf";}]]></xe:this.addressBookDb>
            </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
        </xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="maxRowCount" value="1000">
            </xp:dojoAttribute>
        </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
    </xe:namePicker>

    <xp:br></xp:br>

    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xe:djextListTextBox id="djextListTextBox1"
        value="#{document1.ACHApprovers}" multipleTrim="true">
        <xe:this.multipleSeparator><![CDATA[#{javascript:"\n"}]]></xe:this.multipleSeparator>
    </xe:djextListTextBox>
    <xp:br></xp:br>

    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xe:djextNameTextBox id="djextNameTextBox1" multipleTrim="true">
        <xe:this.multipleSeparator><![CDATA[#{javascript:"\n"}]]></xe:this.multipleSeparator>
    </xe:djextNameTextBox></xp:view>
```

Comment: Bryan - if you continue to have issues, consider checking out the Dojo Name Picker I released last week on OpenNTF:

http://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Dojo%20Name%20Picker/summary

You can see a demo here:  http://demos.xpage.me/xpageme/dojonamepicker.nsf

Answer (score 1):

This is something I have experienced before. Dojo Name TextBox won't work with multiple seperators other than ",".

Picker stores values as expected. But the component renders values as an attribute to a span within the widget. So `\n` or space will not work anyway. But it won't work with other characters like ";", "|" etc.

For the first part, ListTextBox prints values as they are. NameTextBox works almost like ListTextBox, except it extracts CN component from name values. To do the same on ListTextBox, add `displayLabel="true"` attribute.